# Parsing JSON data with php - Data coming back empty

Tags: php, json

I have a piece of JSON that I'm parsing with php. I need to get one of the pieces of data out of it.

Here's the output of the json when I do a print_r:

```
Array ( [deviceId] => 07a9727e-3fe5-4f44-9765-134388241f39 [programId] => 3895 [serviceId] => 19977 [createdAt] => 2013-12-12T07:19:04.466Z [updatedAt] => 2013-12-12T07:19:04.466Z [objectId] => 7TxmL2GiXq )
```

Here's my code trying to extract deviceId:

```
$objectData = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($objectData);
$deviceId = $objectData->deviceId;
```

$deviceId is coming back empty.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
$deviceId = $objectData['deviceId'];
```

You are using the optional second parameter TRUE in your [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) call, which converts it into an associative array instead of an object.

Alternatively:

```
$objectData = json_decode($data);
$deviceId = $objectData->deviceId; // Works
```

Comment: awesome! this works! I knew it was something small I was overlooking. Thanks so much.